# How return only value from Database column value in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have created a function to return the Database column value. The function returns value well. But it is not the format that I want. I have explained my problem below by code.

Function:

```
async function getHtmlNoteContent(quote_id){
  try{
   const connection = await mysql.createConnection(config.mysql.credentials);
   const [note] = await connection.query(`select notes_html from table where id = ${quote_id}`);
   connection.end();
   console.log('ppppp -->',JSON.stringify(note));
   return JSON.stringify(note);
  }catch (e) {
    utils.error500(req, res, e.message);
  }
}
```

above function return value like this -->

```
ppppp --> [{"notes_html":"<p>column value</p>"}]
```

But I want -->

```
ppppp --> <p>column value</p>
```

Can someone show me how can I do this? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clearly see that your `note` variable currently holds an array with 1 object and that object has a property of `notes_html` that you want to return.

First, you need to access the object which you do by: `note[0]`. Second, you want to get only the property of `notes_html` of that object which can do by: `note[0]['notes_html']` or `note[0].notes_html`.

So, instead of:

```
return JSON.stringify(note);
```

do this:

```
return note[0].notes_html; // or note[0]['notes_html']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your result is an array of JSON objects with a single key `notes_html`

To access this result, you can get the first element of the note array using array indexing `note[0]`

To then specifically access the key within the object you want, you can pass the key to retrieve the value with `note[0]['notes_html']`

Producing the line `console.log('ppppp -->',note[0]['notes_html']);`